# Erro: Cannot find data type long

Tags: sql, sql-server, tipagem, sql-server-2012

Estou tentando criar uma procedure no SQL Server 2012, mas ele está dando o seguinte erro na assinatura dela.

```
Mensagem 2715, Nível 16, Estado 3, Procedimento MINHAPROCEDURE, Linha 6
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type long.
Parameter or variable '@IDCatOrigem' has an invalid data type.
Mensagem 2715, Nível 16, Estado 3, Procedimento MINHAPROCEDURE, Linha 6
Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type long.
Parameter or variable '@IDCatDestino' has an invalid data type.
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MINHAPROCEDURE
    (@IDCatOrigem [long], 
    @IDCatDestino [long])
AS
BEGIN
```

Já tentei sem os parenteses, sem os colchetes e nada... Como se cria uma procedure com parâmetros de entrada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tipo `long` não existe no SQL Server. Use o [`bigint`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) no lugar, é a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 3):

Veja o que o erro diz

> Column, parameter, or variable #1: **Cannot find data type long.**
>   Parameter or variable '@IDCatOrigem' has an **invalid data type.**

Não existe o tipo de dados `long` no SQL Server, o equivalente é o tipo [`bigint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).